# How to get next earliest date from another categorical value (within the same column) in PySpark?

Tags: python, dataframe, date, pyspark, databricks

I'm not sure my question title makes much sense so I shall explain with an example below.

I have a dataframe (in Databricks using PySpark) that looks like the below:

As of November 2020, table Markdown is now supported on all Stack Exchange sites.

| Date | Category |
| --- | --- |
| 2021-01-02 | A |
| 2021-01-06 | A |
| 2021-01-07 | A |
| 2021-01-10 | B |
| 2021-01-15 | A |
| 2021-01-16 | A |
| 2021-01-18 | A |
| 2021-01-23 | B |
| 2021-01-25 | A |

And I'm trying to get the date difference (in days) between category A and the next category B, example below:

| Date | Category | Days Diff |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-01-02 | A | 8 |
| 2021-01-06 | A | 4 |
| 2021-01-07 | A | 3 |
| 2021-01-10 | B |  |
| 2021-01-15 | A | 8 |
| 2021-01-16 | A | 7 |
| 2021-01-18 | A | 5 |
| 2021-01-23 | B |  |
| 2021-01-25 | A | ... |

Does anyone have any ideas of the best way to do this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use window function to achieve this.

First, create a column that contains only the Date when Category is B.

```py
df = df.withColumn('BDate', when(df.Category == 'B', df.Date))

+----------+--------+----------+
|      Date|Category|     BDate|
+----------+--------+----------+
|2021-01-02|       A|      null|
|2021-01-06|       A|      null|
|2021-01-07|       A|      null|
|2021-01-10|       B|2021-01-10|
|2021-01-15|       A|      null|
...
```

Then, create a window that can look up any following rows from the current row and find the first `BDate` within the window. Take the date difference between the current `Date` and the `BDate` that is found.

```py
w = Window.orderBy('Date').rowsBetween(0, Window.unboundedFollowing)
df = df.withColumn('Days Diff', F.datediff(F.first(df.BDate, ignorenulls=True).over(w), df.Date))
```

Result

```
+----------+--------+----------+---------+
|      Date|Category|     BDate|Days Diff|
+----------+--------+----------+---------+
|2021-01-02|       A|      null|        8|
|2021-01-06|       A|      null|        4|
|2021-01-07|       A|      null|        3|
|2021-01-10|       B|2021-01-10|        0|
|2021-01-15|       A|      null|        8|
|2021-01-16|       A|      null|        7|
|2021-01-18|       A|      null|        5|
|2021-01-23|       B|2021-01-23|        0|
|2021-01-25|       A|      null|     null|
+----------+--------+----------+---------+
```

Comment: cool, I appreciate if you approve my answer if this worked.